# Azure chat bot welcome message is not triggering on webchat

Tags: azure, chat, chatbot

I have been using azure chatbot framework for my chat-bot development and now Welcome message is not triggering on webchat automatically on webchat while initialization .It is working as expected on client emulator and  azure cloud aw well ;But while opening the chat window on browser ,welcome message  is showing only after when user prompts an input .